# Nexus 7 stuck at Google logo, and system recovery, and OEM locked

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, boot, nexus-7

**Short version:**

- Normal startup: Stuck at Google screen.
- Unlock bootloader: Stuck at the selection.
- Recovery mode: Stuck at Google screen.

---

**Long version**

My Nexus 7 (2013) had always been fine, and I liked stock Android very much, thus saw no need to unlock the bootloader. When the 5.1 OTA came, I updated my N7 and it started crashing and restarting on its own. One day, it restarted again and got stuck at the Google screen.

Of course, the first thing I did was to get the Nexus Root Toolkit, and tried flashing stock ROM. Of course, it didn't work since it was OEM locked. When I tried to unlock the bootloader, I was prompted with the screen asking if I want to unlock and wipe all data. I selected unlock and pressed the power button. Then it froze (I left it for 8 hours, plugged it into a power outlet).

The next logical thing to do was to start recovery mode in the fastboot to do a factory reset, except it simply switched to the Google screen and was stuck there.

I've read many articles, but it's always one of the three issues I have. They often refer to using a method that involves an area where it's affected by the other problems.

How to recover from this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a common bug that has been reported on recently by [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/04/19/reports-suggest-2013-nexus-7-units-are-failing-at-an-alarming-rate-not-likely-a-result-of-firmware-updates/). To summarize:

> Affected units stop booting at the "Google" logo screen.   Attempts to
>   unlock the device through fastboot fail at the "erasing userdata..."
>   step, leaving the devices locked.  Some users report successfully
>   flashing factory images on unlocked devices, but this still doesn't
>   fix the problem.  There are mixed reports about starting up in
>   Recovery, with some users complaining that the Nexus 7 freezes, and
>   others being able to get in to perform some maintenance.

There are no know solutions at this time. Sorry to bring bad news. I hope I'm not right.

Comment: Thank you, at least now I know I'm not the only one with this problem, and that some of the solutions I've been trying aren't going to work afterall.

Comment: Yeah, it sucks. You might try contacting Nexus support, just to see if they'll do anything. Not sure they will depending on when you got the N7.

Answer (score 2):

Searching through Google, I found this thread: [Android Central Forums - Nexus 7 stuck on Google logo screen on boot up](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2013/361895-nexus-7-stuck-google-logo-screen-boot-up-4.html).

Someone there suggested knocking the backside of Nexus 7.

I did that and it worked, Google boot animation appeared. My Nexus 7 (2013) is ok for now.

Comment: I've read on several websites that say knocking on the sides or the back seemed to solve the problem for some users. It raised a bit of hope in me, but I've not had any luck so far. Could you maybe specify the following:
1. Where on the tablet did you knock it?
2. When during the startup did you knock it?
3. How long did you have to wait?
Every bit of information helps, thank you!

Comment: Tapping on the back of my Asus Nexus tablet fixed allowed me to leave the logo screen and boot properly as well.  I would like to understand why that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well, and was stuck at the Google logo whatever I tried.

I was able to unlock the bootloader and install custom recovery (TWRP), and a custom ROM using the "Nexus Root Toolkit" and fastboot. But I was still stuck at the Google logo. But then I found this post and gave the tablet a few knocks on the back and sides, and suddenly it started booting into the custom ROM I installed!

EDIT: My touch was also unresponsive. But now even that works :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be a battery problem if your stuck at Google logo. I couldnt get my Nexus7 2012 to boot up and it was stuck. Replaced the battery and it started charging.